# What is meant by REFERENCED_OWNER in Oracle SQL tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two schemas A and B and both has many tables.

table t1 in schema A has dependency to schema B as a REFERENCED_OWNER.

What does REFERENCED_OWNER means ?

Answer (score 1):

The referenced owner is the owner of the object where your object in schema A has dependencies on.
A schema, can be seen as a user who is also an object owner.